# Error when including date picker in callback in Dash

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am using Quandl API and would like to write a callback to update the data and date range shown in the graph.

First I defined a function to get the data I want:

```
def indicator_select(indi='NY_GDS_TOTL_ZS',coun='WLD'):
    quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = key
    data=quandl.get(f'WWDI/{coun}_{indi}')
    return data
```

Next, I included the `DatePickerRange` as shown below:

```
html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id='date-picker1',
            min_date_allowed=datetime(1970, 1, 1),
            max_date_allowed=datetime.today(),
            start_date = datetime(1970, 1, 1),
            end_date = datetime.today()
            )
        ])
```

And, lastly, I wrote the callback - which was working fine before including the date component. For the data only, it was updating the graph as expected.

```
@app.callback(Output(component_id='graph1', 
                    component_property='figure'),
              [Input(component_id='country-list1', 
                    component_property='value'),
              Input(component_id='indicator-list1', 
                    component_property='value'),
              Input(component_id='date-picker1', component_property='start_date'),
              Input(component_id='date-picker1', component_property='end_date')])

def update_graph(start_date,end_date,indi=indicator_options,coun=country_options):
    df = indicator_select(coun, indi)
    df = df.loc[start_date: end_date]
    graph_content = dict(data=line_plot(df),
                        layout=go.Layout(
                            title=str(country.loc[indi, "Country"]) + 
                                    ' - ' + 
                                    str(indicator.loc[coun, "INDICATOR"]),
                            yaxis=dict(hoverformat='.1f',
                                    showgrid=False),
                            paper_bgcolor='#F7F7F7',
                            plot_bgcolor='#F7F7F7',
                            )
                        )
    return graph_content
```

As a result, I get the following error message:

***quandl.errors.quandl_error.NotFoundError: (Status 404) (Quandl Error QECx02) You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and try again.***

I am having a hard time understanding why when I include the start and end date in the callback it will return me this error, and when I delete the dates it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of inputs. You added the dates to the end of the list of `Inputs`, but put them as the first args in the function. It should look like this:

```py
@app.callback(Output(component_id='graph1', 
                    component_property='figure'),
              [Input(component_id='country-list1', 
                    component_property='value'),
              Input(component_id='indicator-list1', 
                    component_property='value'),
              Input(component_id='date-picker1', component_property='start_date'),
              Input(component_id='date-picker1', component_property='end_date')])

def update_graph(indi=indicator_options,coun=country_options, start_date, end_date):
    # content of func
```